# Formally, why can we start induction in any base case?

Tags: induction

I'm taking a course in Set Theory, and I want to prove that finite product of $\omega$ has cardinality $\omega$. I already have that $P(\omega \times \omega) = \omega$. So I can say that using ordinary induction we have that for any $n \in \omega$ we have that $P(\omega_1 \times \ldots \times \omega_n) = \omega$, where $\omega_i=\omega$.

But formally, induction have as base case $n = 0$ and here, I want to use induction with base case $n = 2$. Intuitively it's clear for me that there is no problem, but I can't argue with formal arguments why if the base case is not zero, I can still make induction.

Comment: The cheap answer is to define $m=n-2$ and induct on $m$.

Comment: Or you can say for $n \ge 2$ and start with the base case of $P(\omega \times \omega)=\omega$.

Comment: @Obinna: Clearly you are so well aware of the canonical meaning assigned to these symbols used here. Might as well suggest to use $\Bbb R^i$ as the variables.